# Elastic Beanstalk Redirect Missing Colon?

Tags: amazon-web-services, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a website setup in Elastic Beanstalk, but when I enter the `website.com` URL in a browser, it auto directs me to `https//website.com` and is missing the colon... it works if I add www.website.com though... or if I type https://www.website.com.

The contents of a `.ebextensions/prod01.config` file

```
files:
  /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000644"
    content: |
      # Elastic Beanstalk Managed

      # Elastic Beanstalk managed configuration file
      # Some configuration of nginx can be by placing files in /etc/nginx/conf.d
      # using Configuration Files.
      # http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/customize-containers.html 


      upstream nodejs {
          server 127.0.0.1:8081;
          keepalive 256;
      }

      server {
          listen 8080;
          server_name website.com;

          if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
              set $year $1;
              set $month $2;
              set $day $3;
              set $hour $4;
          }
          access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
          access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;

          location / {
              set $redirect 0;
              if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                set $redirect 1;
              }

              if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
                set $redirect 0;
              }

              if ($redirect = 1) {
                return 301 https://www.heyants.com$request_uri;
              }

              proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
              proxy_set_header   Connection "";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }
      }

      server {
          listen 8080;
            server_name www.website.com;

          if ($time_iso8601 ~ "^(\d{4})-(\d{2})-(\d{2})T(\d{2})") {
              set $year $1;
              set $month $2;
              set $day $3;
              set $hour $4;
          }
          access_log /var/log/nginx/healthd/application.log.$year-$month-$day-$hour healthd;
          access_log  /var/log/nginx/access.log  main;


          location / {
              set $redirect 0;
              if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
                set $redirect 1;
              }

              if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
                set $redirect 0;
              }

              if ($redirect = 1) {
                return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
              }

              proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
              proxy_set_header   Connection "";
              proxy_http_version 1.1;
              proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
              proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
              proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
          }

      gzip on;
      gzip_comp_level 4;
      gzip_types text/html text/plain text/css application/json application/x-javascript text/xml application/xml application/xml+rss text/javascript;

      }
  /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/configdeploy/post/99_kill_default_nginx.sh:
    owner: root
    group: root
    mode: "000755"
    content: |
      #!/bin/bash -xe
      rm -f /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf
      if [[ -e /etc/init/nginx.conf ]] ; then
        echo Using initctl to stop and start nginx
        initctl stop nginx || true
        initctl start nginx
      else
        echo Using service to stop and start nginx
        service nginx stop 
        service nginx start
      fi

container_commands:
  removeconfig:
    command: "rm -f /tmp/deployment/config/#etc#nginx#conf.d#00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"
```

## Update

I have updated to use one of the AWS references provided below; but one condition of the redirect still does not work; I hope that with this clear update a truly canonical solution for all can be found.

- website.com *SUCCESSFULLY REDIRECTS TO* https://www.website.com
- www.website.com *SUCCESSFULLY REDIRECTS TO* https://www.website.com
- https://www.website.com *SUCCESSFULLY REDIRECTS TO* https://www.website.com
- http://www.website.com *SUCCESSFULLY REDIRECTS TO* 
  https://website.com
- http://website.com **FAILS TO REDIRECT TO** https://www.website.com
- https://website.com **FAILS TO REDIRECT TO** https://www.website.com; it takes them to https//www.website.com (Missing a colon)

Comment: Can you get into the server and see what does the nginx file look like? You can also add `nginx -T` command after the update which will dump all the contents of the file to be sure if it is being updated

Comment: Can you try this approach instead? https://github.com/awsdocs/elastic-beanstalk-samples/blob/master/configuration-files/aws-provided/security-configuration/https-redirect/nodejs/https-redirect-nodejs.config. Instead of using `=`, use `!=` for the `http` header check

Comment: Is there a reason nginx is used instead of application load balancer, Is it a single instance environment?

Answer (score 1):

I tested with your configuration:

**Request: GET http://website.com/ --> Reponse: 301, Location: http://https://www.website.com/**

the second semicolon is removed by browser. It is unexpected, bug perhaps.
Can you try to use rewrite instead:

```
listen 8080;
server_name website.com;
...
if ($redirect = 1) {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.website.com$1 permanent;
}
```

**Request: GET https://website.com/ --> FAILED**

On website.com rule it redirect to https://www.website.com/ only if its http. If you want https://website.com/ redirects to https://www.website.com/ then add

```
listen 8080;
server_name website.com;
...
if ($host = "website.com") {
    rewrite ^(.*) https://www.website.com$1 permanent;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using `return 308 https://...`? Try also _302_ and _307_. Sorry can only suggest trial and error as this nginx behaviour (bug?) does not conform the [doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_rewrite_module.html#return).

Answer (score 0):

Update your AWS Elastic Beanstalk config file that is residing here *"/etc/nginx/conf.d/00_elastic_beanstalk_proxy.conf"* with the following content according to your requirements:

```
location / {
    set $redirect 0;
    if ($http_x_forwarded_proto != "https") {
        set $redirect 1;
    }
    if ($http_user_agent ~* "ELB-HealthChecker") {
        set $redirect 0;
    }
    if ($redirect = 1) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    }

    proxy_pass  http://nodejs;
    proxy_set_header   Connection "";
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header        Host            $host;
    proxy_set_header        X-Real-IP       $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header        X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```